# OTP Verification - Which approach will lead to better and consistent UX? (Screenshot included)

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design

I'm designing a screen for OTP verification. The design looks similar to this. [Taken from here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/111737/in-a-verify-otp-modal-box-verify-otp-button-will-be-first-or-resend-otp-link)

[image]

My questions are,

1. Should I auto-verify the OTP when the user has entered all the 6 digits or Should I expect the user to press the Validate button? What will be the better and consistent user-experience?
2. If I auto-verify the OTP once the user is done with entering the 6 digits, Are there any security concerns? (Assuming, I'm limiting the number of validation attempts on the backend.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep language consistent: make sure the action is the same as the button. Change 'Validate' to 'Verify'as the system says ""...to **verify** your account"

Aside from that I see nothing wrong with automatically proceeding the user if a correct verification code has been entered as it saves the user a click.

My bank does this when I enter a verification code to set up a new payment.

But with that scenario, what would the system do if a wrong code was entered? It would have to feedback to the user somehow or other; you need to consider that interaction too.

Either way, test with users whatever you build.

Edit: and remove the button if auto verify; you don't need it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. For the case when an incorrect was entered, I'm displaying a proper error message and a red underline is added to each input. I hope this is enough. This is for the mobile users. What do you think?

Comment: 'a red underline is added to each input' - can you elaborate?

Comment: Why Verify instead Validate? You should explain the suggestions.

Comment: to keep the language consistent "...to verify your account"

Fairly obvious and basic UX. But I should have explained that. Will edit answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I see a large <kbd>Validate</kbd> button, I'll assume that's what I have to click. If instead, the form auto-submits, that will break my expectations and make me feel like this application is unpredictable.

It's not wrong to auto-submit the code, but make it obvious that there's not something that I have to do after typing in order for this to submit.

---

I'd recommend you ask the folks at [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com) about any security concerns you may have during this design process. They're much better equipped to adequately address these concerns.

Comment: So, Should I consider removing the `Validate` button if I'm auto-submitting the form?

Comment: - yes, you don't need it. But the system needs to tell the user to enter a code and that it is automatically verified

Comment: Yes, I'd do away with the button if the user will never have a chance to click it.